# How to pass user input to parameter in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, youtube-dl

This script utilizing youtubedl+aria2c features to download video from YouTube.

Can't complete *Option 4* for specific format. I created **formatF** variable that storing user input and passing this value to another variable **DnSelect**

```
SET DnSelect=--no-check-certificate -f "%formatF%" --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args "-x16 -s16 -k1M
```

My Code/Script:

```
@echo off
SET DnBest=--no-check-certificate -f 22 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args "-x16 -s16 -k1M"
SET DnSelect=--no-check-certificate -f "%formatF%" --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args "-x16 -s16 -k1M"
SET Destination=""%home%"\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s"
if not -%1-==-- SET URL=%*  
if -%1-==-- goto fopNew 

:top
CLS
ECHO URL: %URL%
ECHO ----------------------
ECHO Available operations:
ECHO ----------------------
ECHO .

ECHO 1. Best of all
ECHO 2. Check all formats available
ECHO 3. New URI
ECHO 4. Select specific format
ECHO 5. Exit
SET /P operation=Which operation would you like to do?:
if "%operation%"=="n" goto fopNew
if "%operation%"=="N" goto fopNew
if "%operation%"=="1" goto fop1
if "%operation%"=="2" goto fopFormat
if "%operation%"=="3" goto :fopNew
if "%operation%"=="4" goto :fopSelect
if "%operation%"=="5" goto :fopQuit

:fop1
ECHO Best:
youtube-dl %DnBest% -o %Destination% %URL%
pause
goto top

:fopFormat
ECHO List of all possible formats:
youtube-dl -F %URL%
pause
goto top

:fopSelect
ECHO List of all possible formats:
youtube-dl -F %URL%
ECHO Enter number of desired format from all possible formats:
SET /P formatF=:
ECHO Download selected format:
youtube-dl %DnSelect% -o %Destination% %URL%
pause
goto top

:fopNew
SET /P URL=Enter the video URL:
goto top

:fopQuit
@echo off
```

Output:

> ERROR: requested format not available

I just want to select supported format from list of available formats and download it.

Comment: You are setting `DnSelect` with `%formatF%` before it is defined. Put that line just before `youtube-dl %DnSelect% -o %Destination% %URL%`

Answer (score 2):

As you are setting variables at the outset, you'll need to escape some of your **`%`** characters:

```bat
Set "DnBest=--no-check-certificate -f 22 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args "-x16 -s16 -k1M""
Set "DnSelect=--no-check-certificate -f "%%formatF%%" --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args "-x16 -s16 -k1M""
Set "Destination=""%home%"\%%%%(title)s.%%%%(ext)s""
```

In the example above, I've assumed that when the script is invoked, the variable, `%formatF%` is at that time undefined, so I have escaped the percent characters in it. I have also assumed, *because it isn't set within the code provided*, that the variable `%home%` is pre-defined so I have left it enclosed in single percents, *(you will need to use double percents if it is defined within the script, but not shown in your snippet)*.